# Why are my collection item's text not displaying?

Tags: c#, collections, propertygrid

I am coding a C# forms application where I have an object for a PropertGrid. This object has a Collection of type T1, where each item in this Collection can also have a Collection of type T1.

The object T1 also has an object of type T2 that is selected from a Collection.

When creating an object of type T1, the Collection of T2 is retrieved correctly using a StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context) function and the objects are displayed in a drop down list that can be selected, and the value is set correctly.

The problem is when an object of type T1 has a Collection of type T1. When trying to display the Collection of T2, the values in the drop down list do not have a text associated with them. When looking at the StandardValuesCollection that is returned, the data is correct, but will not display with the name. The count is also correct.

Why would this be?

If needed, I will write up some code for this post when possible, I am wondering if there is a concept that is incorrect with my code or I have missed something simple.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to override the ToString() method for the T2 type. Kindly do this and if no text appears please post your code so we can see it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the problem was with the convert code. I was not looking in the correct collection.